# Understanding super in Python

Tags: python, inheritance, super, diamond-problem

Could you please explain to me how to write the deadly diamond in Python? I saw many examples of similar code without using constructor arguments, but once I start using arguments thigs start being messy...

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.b = b
        super().__init__(a)

class C(A):
    def __init__(self, a, c):
        self.c = c
        super().__init__(a)

class D(B, C):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d):
        self.d = d
        # How do I pass a and b to B.__init__
        # and a and c to C.__init__
        # using super() ?
        super().__init__(a, b, c) #???

d = D(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: In your code, you wrote, "How to write what I want?". So, what do you want??

Comment: @Anwarvic That `self.a`, ...`self.d` get initialized with the values of `a`, ...`d`.

Comment: @Anwarvic  the OP wants that, when you initialise D, value "b" gets assigned to class B and value "c" gets assigned to class C.

Comment: I edited the question to clarify the point

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would probably be that every subclass accepts a dict of kwargs, and passes it to the upper level:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, b, **kwargs):
        self.b = b
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

class C(A):
    def __init__(self, c, **kwargs):
        self.c = c
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

class D(B, C):
    def __init__(self, d, **kwargs):
        self.d = d
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

d = D(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4)

print(d.a, d.b, d.c, d.d)
# 1 2 3 4
```

At each call, `__init__` gets the argument it requires, and passes the remaining ones to the parent class. The only drawback is that you have to pass the arguments as keywords.

Comment: There IS another drawback: the initializers signature will not mention all required arguments (ie `D` only explicitely requires `d`, while it really requires `a`, `b` and `c` too).

Answer (score 0):

Your subclasses initializers don't have compatible signatures, which is the key to proper cooperative super calls.

The simple solution here is to make those signatures compatible - canonically by adding support for varargs and arbitrary keyword args all along the chain, ie:

```
# NB: Python3 required, won't work in Py2

class A:
    def __init__(self, a, *args, **kwargs):
        self.a = a

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, a, b, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(a, *args, **kwargs)
        self.b = b

class C(A):
    def __init__(self, a, c, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(a, *args, **kwargs)
        self.c = c

class D(B, C):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(a, b=b, c=c, *args, **kwargs)
        self.d = d


d = D(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

This will of course not solve each and every possible issue with multiple inheritance and cooperative `super` calls, but MI *is* tricky, and there are restrictions to what's possible anyway.